# Neat XML from T-SQL

Tags: xml, t-sql, sqlxml

Lets say we have a table "Names":

```
ID    Name    Surname
1     Matt    Smith
2     John    Doe
```

How would you write some SQLXML to generate this:

```
<people>
  <person>
    <name>Matt</name>
    <surname>Smith</surname>
  <person>
  <person>
    <name>John</name>
    <surname>Doe</surname>
  <person>
</people>
```

The best I've got is this:

```
select r.value('Name[1]', 'nvarchar(10)'), r.value('Surname[1]', 'nvarchar(10)')
from Names
for xml path('people')
```

Which gives me:

```
<people>
  <name>Matt</name>
  <surname>Smith</surname>
</people>
<people>
  <name>John</name>
  <surname>Doe</surname>
</people>
```

In short, how do I wrap the whole lot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
   Name,
   Surname
FROM 
   dbo.Names
FOR XML PATH('person'), ROOT('people')
```

The `FOR XML PATH` defines the tag to surround each individual row, while the `FOR XML ... ROOT` defines the root element surrounding the collection of rows.

Comment: Clean solution ! did this long back ! got the idea back ! thx !

Comment: And if you want attributes in elements, you simply define the column name as "@columnname". Note that in this case you have to define the attribute column first, or you get an error. Also, if you use subqueries which also output XML, you have to include "type" like so: "for xml path('elementname'), type" (or it'll escape all the XML that comes from the subquery). In that case you can omit root and use "elementroot" as an alias, it'll take over that role.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this an all xml way,

You can have a Variable,

```
Declare @XMLOP xml
SET @XMLOP  = '<people></people>'

set @XMLOP.modify('       
insert (select r.value('Name[1]', 'nvarchar(10)'), r.value('Surname[1]', 'nvarchar(10)') 
        from Names 
        for xml path('Person'))
after (/people)[1]       
');

SELECT @XMLOP;
```